# Can we extend c.p. normal maps on a finite von Neumann algebra $M$ to $L_0(M)_+$?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, positivity, traces

Suppose that $M$ is a von Neumann algebra with a finite, normal, faithful trace $\tau$. Let $T\colon M\to M$ be a completely positive, normal map.

> Can $T$ be extended to a `positively linear map' on $L_0(M)_+$, the positive part of the *-algebra of $\tau$-measurable operators affiliated with $M$?

The idea is obvious. We express a positive element from $L_0(M)$ as the limit of an increasing net of positive elements $(x_a)$ in $M$. In this case we ought to define

$Tx = \sup Tx_a$,

as the net $(Tx_a)$ is increasing due to positivity of $T$. This definition readily works for $T=1_M\cdot \tau$, however in full generality there is an issue with the choice of $(x_a)$. I don't think it is obvious that $Tx$ does not depend on  $(x_a)$.

Comment: Maybe I missing something... But what do you intend to do about "infinite values"?  E.g. $\tau$ does extend to $L_0(M)_+$, but it may take the value $\infty$.  So what are you hoping to do with general CP maps?

Comment: It seems to me that a normal cp map should extend to a map between extended positive parts of $M$. Would that be helpful?

Comment: @Wasilwski. What do you mean by the extended positive part of $M$?